# Difference between a function and a macro

Tags: c, embedded

I would like to know what is the advantage of using a macro instead of declaring a function.

For example I found this line in a header file of an USB library for an ATMEL microcontroller:

```
#define  udd_detach_device()                 ( Clr_bits(UDP->UDP_TXVC, UDP_TXVC_PUON))
```

Why is it defined like this, and not like a function?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Macro: used for text substitution in source; Function: used to aid in calculating values, setting up data structures, ... you cannot really replace one with the other

Comment: Also, functions are called at run-time while macros are expanded (substituted) at compile-time.

Comment: For your specific case, maybe this is a common operation and the writers simply wanted a simple way to write the expansion that doesn't result in the extra run-time overhead of calling another function.

Comment: Yes I know that macro are text substition for the compiler, but I wonder what is the advantage (or disadvantage) of doing that instead of declaring a void -> voind function that performs the same operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this `#define` does is replace every textual occurrence of `udd_detach_device()` in your source with the following text `( Clr_bits(UDP->UDP_TXVC, UDP_TXVC_PUON))`.

This is done before your code is compiled, in the so called pre-processing phase.

You should see this C pre-processor (CPP) phase as a text-editing phase in which parts of the code can be replaced or left out. The CPP recognises a limited set of editing commands that all start with `#`.

Read [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) for more background.

Comment: What is the advantage of doing that instead of declaring a void -> void function that does the same operation?

Comment: @Wheatley it really depends on the use case.

Comment: @Jabberwocky in this case the macro's operation is clearing a bit in a register.

Comment: @Wheatley then using a macro rather than a function is probably a good idea, because if you call a function you get quite some overhead, which might be a good idea to avoid especially on micro controllers

Comment: @Jabberwocky Depends on compiler optimisation. Many compilers are capable of inlining simple functions.